# django import error between 2 apps

Tags: django, import

I have a problem where i think i get circular imports. Let me explain.
I got 2 apps, "heroes" and "towns"

in "towns" I made:

```
class Town(models.Model):
    """ town objects keep track of all buildings, location, respawns etc """

    controlled = models.BooleanField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Hero)
```

in "heroes" I got:

```
class Hero(models.Model):
    """ parent model for Heroes, both NPC and Player """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Town)
```

now when import my needed classes, i get this error:

```
File "/home/ikke/panda/Buah/apps/heroes/models.py", line 4, in <module>
from apps.towns.models import Town
File "/home/ikke/panda/Buah/apps/towns/models.py", line 4, in <module>
from apps.heroes.models import Hero
ImportError: cannot import name Hero
```

I also tried to use the following in one of my models:

```
location = models.ForeignKey('apps.towns.Town')
```

but then I get the following error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
heroes.hero: 'location' has a relation with model apps.towns.model.Town, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

I have been having troubles with this for quite some while and tried other stackoverflow topics as well, but still i haven't found the solution.

Can someone please explain what goes wrong, and how i can solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key represents a one to many relationships. This is used to relate a model instance with several instances of other model (ie. a profile can be related with several pictures).

If you want to have only one hero per town and only one town per hero you need a [one to one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

If you want to have many heros in town and many towns per hero you need a [many to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

If you want many heros in a town but only one town per hero or many towns per hero and only one hero per town you need a [one to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/). Have in mind that the "many" part in the relationship is in the model that holds the ForeignKey Field.

With this you should not need to import models at both sides.

If town is owned by only one hero and hero can have only one town it is a one to one relationships. Check the documentation for reverse relationship. IE. If you put the relationship in hero you can get the hero from town using the reverse.

Comment: I am not sure how this works for me. Every hero in my game has always 1 town(and 1 town only) as location. But a town, can be owned by a Hero. so thats a different relationship. (town is always owned by 1 hero)  or am i missing something now?

Comment: That looks like a one to one relationship to me.